# How can I check input of USB?

Tags: usb, design, input, hardware

I have following wire as shown below, one end has male USB connector and other end has four wires. I know, when connected to laptop, the RED one acts as voltage source and BLACK as ground. If I give 2 bits data input to GREEN and YELLOW one, is there any software or API for (Python, C or any other language) to know about state of those two wires ? I mean to check if GREEN or YELLOW one have a voltage or not.

[image]

Please guide me if I am asking the wrong question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you cannot sense the USB wire state directly. USB is a much more complex interface than that, it is no comparison to the old style serial and parallel ports that could be used for direct I/O with a simple driver program. A complex handshake is exchanged with the PC even before the first byte of 'real' data/payload can sent.

Maybe your PC has a parallel port that can be used? Or you should use a USB to GPIO converter which are broadly available for varying prices (both extremely high and extremely low).

Comment: Example: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/718 I don't have any experience with this module, but it looks like up to the job. There are many similar alternatives available if you look around a bit.

Comment: Just a small addition: you cannot abuse a USB port like this because the handshake happens at a much lower level than what you can access with normal programming languages. Parts of the handshake happen in the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

What is your ultimate goal?  If it is to observe the USB protocol, you can use a [relatively inexpensive](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8938) or [relatively expensive](http://www.tek.com/logic-analyzer) logic analyzer.

If your goal is to capture bytes on your computer, you can get a USB debugger for your operating system (e.g., OS X has a free USB Debug Kit).

If your goal is to have an easy way to determine if you put a voltage onto an input, you'd be better off using a USB-->GPIO, as jippie suggested, or you could go down the (more expensive) arduino route and have a lot of room to grow if you wanted to do more stuff with the inputs prior to analysis on the computer.

If you really want a super-simple way to get a voltage value into your computer without buying new hardware, [jippie's suggestion to use the parallel port is a good one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/72213/how-can-i-check-input-of-usb/72216#72216), and you could also investigate using your microphone input as a jerry-built solution.